# multidimensional mutable Vectors: possible? if so, how?

Tags: arrays, haskell, multidimensional-array

i notice that the generate function is not defined for mutable vectors. i'm wondering if there is another way to define multidimensional mutable Vectors in haskell

Answer (score 5):

I assume your mean something from the `vector` package, like `Data.Vector.Mutable`?

It provides several ways to create and fill mutable arrays, such as with [`replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#v:replicate). However, the `vector` package is for 1-dimensional, growable vectors, not multi-dimensional arrays.

For n>1 dimensions, you need to either code the index manually, or use [`repa`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) or [`hmatrix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix).

`repa`, in particular, is interesting, as it also provides automagically parallel operations, and you can [fill one from a vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/2.0.0.3/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa.html#g:2). However, `repa` arrays are immutable, and rely on fusion for a nice interface.

If you need *mutable* and *multi-dimensional* arrays, you might have to resort to the old school `array` package, and one of the `MArray` types.

Comment: thanks don! yes it is mutable and multidimensional arrays i am after. i am currently using MArray. thanks for the clarification